# Calling lean on document throws TypeError: lean is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose, and I'm trying to create an app that uses the OpenWeatherMap API. After requesting the data form the API, I save them to my MongoDB and then I want to return the results as a json, so I call the following function:

```
async function saveForecast(data) {

// Code here for creating the "forecastList" from the data and fetching the "savedLocation" from the DB

const newForecast = new Forecast({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    location: savedLocation,
    city: {
        id: data.city.id,
        name: data.city.name,
        coordinates: data.city.coord,
        country: data.city.country
    },
    forecasts: forecastList
});

try {
    const savedForecast = await newForecast.save();
    return savedForecast.populate('location').lean().exec(); //FIXME: The lean() here throws  TypeError: savedForecast.populate(...).lean is not a function
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while saving forecast. ' + err);
}
}
```

The "newForecast" is being saved successfully in the DB, however when I try adding the .lean() after my populate I get the following error:
`TypeError: savedForecast.populate(...).lean is not a function`

I've used lean() on find queries and it works fine, but I can't get it to work with my "newForecast" object, even though the "savedForecast" is a mongoose document, as the debugger shows me.

Any ideas why lean() is not working? Thank you!

Comment: which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mongoose 5.2.15, and after updating to 5.3.6 the same error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that `Document` does not have `lean()` method.

`await newForecast.save();` does not return a `Query` but a `Document`. Then running `populate` on a `Document` also returns `Document`. To convert `Document` to a plain JS object you have to use [Document.prototype.toObject()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) method:

```
try {
    const savedForecast = await newForecast.save();
    return savedForecast.populate('location').toObject(); // Wrong! `location` is not populated!
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while saving forecast. ' + err);
}
```

However this code will execute wrongly - population will not be called, because `populate` must receive a callback argument or `execPopulate` (which returns a Promise) has to be called on it. As far as you are using `async/await` I would suggest to use `execPopulate` instead of a callback. And last but not least - populated `location` needs to be leaned:

```
try {
    const savedForecast = await newForecast.save();
    return await savedForecast
      .populate({ path: 'location', options: { lean: true }})
      .execPopulate()
      .then(populatedForecast => populatedForecast.toObject());
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while saving forecast. ' + err);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works. I have misunderstood the use of lean() (and .toObject() for that matter). The weird thing is that my populate was working fine (when not calling .toObject() afterwards), so I got everything mixed up with promises returned by Mongoose. Again, thank you :)

Comment: I know this is an old post. But I couldn't answer to my situation. When I log the populated field, I can see it as with all its keys on terminal. But if I try to access fields of it like

appointment.populatedField.firstName

it says
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'string'. Populated field seen as string. After wasting many hours, I still have no idea what's the problem.